# Recommendations about passing URL parameters like 'fields' and 'include' when creating or updating resources using the JSON:API spec

Tags: json-api

In this scenario, I'm fetching resources using the 'includes' and 'fields' parameters to get a specific response (which is normalized on the client side). What I'd like to do is update a resource or create a new resource but have the response come back in the same format as a resource in my GET request. If this is allowed I assume the way to do this is to pass the 'includes' and 'fields' parameters in the url of the PATCH or POST request in the same way I did in the GET request. However, I don't see any mention of this scenario on https://jsonapi.org/ so I'm curious if this is acceptable or forbidden and am curious as to what the best practices are here.

Answer (score 2):

Requesting the inclusion of related resources using `included` query param and sparse fieldsets is supported for any endpoint that responds with primary data. This is explicitly mentioned for both in the spec as notes in the relevant chapters:

> **Inclusion of Related Resources**
>
> [...]
>
> Note: This section applies to any endpoint that responds with primary data, regardless of the request type. For instance, a server could support the inclusion of related resources along with a POST request to create a resource or relationship.
>
> https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes
>
> **Sparse Fieldsets**
>
> [...]
>
> Note: This section applies to any endpoint that responds with resources as primary or included data, regardless of the request type. For instance, a server could support sparse fieldsets along with a POST request to create a resource.
>
> https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sparse-fieldsets